# Oracle SQL: Combining WHERE statements with different criteria to list aggregate totals

Tags: sql, oracle

**Oracle SQL**:
I have sales data in a DB and I am trying to pull commission totals, per sales person, for year-to-date sales, based on their territory. All sales persons are subject to the constraint that CUSTNO cannot equal `C001`, `C002`, or `C003`. Here is 1 salesperson.

```
SELECT sum(commission) AS Sales_Person_1
FROM salesdata
WHERE state IN ('TX',
                'CA',
                'FL')
  AND CUSTNO NOT IN ('C001',
                     'C002',
                     'C003')
  AND date >= 1/1/2017;
```

That gives me all commission based off this one person in a row, but how do I write a single query to include all other sales people, based off similar territory criteria?

I want it to also sum the same data but based off '`GA`', '`NY`' as a row, '`NH`', '`WA`' as a row, etc.

Ideally I want my data to come back as:

```
Sales_Person_1 $500      
Sales_Person_2 $999   
Sales_Person_3 $888
```

I tried `GROUP BY` but I can't use `WHERE`. I'm lost. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: What's the table structure like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT state_group,
SUM(commission) AS Total_Commission
FROM (
  SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN state IN ('TX', 'CA', 'FL') THEN 'Group 1'
    WHEN state IN ('GA', 'NY') THEN 'Group 2'
    WHEN state IN ('NH', 'WA') THEN 'Group 3'
    ELSE 'Undefined Group'
  END AS state_group,
  commission
  FROM salesdata
  WHERE CUSTNO NOT IN ('C001', 'C002', 'C003')
  AND date >= TO_DATE('1/1/2017', 'd/m/yyyy')
)
GROUP BY state_group
ORDER BY state_group;
```

The CASE statement in the subquery allows you to allocate each of your state values into "groups" or "salespeople". You can rename the "Group 1" or "Group 2" if you want to show different values in your final result. You can also add extra WHEN lines if you have more groups.

The outer query will sum the commission for these groups and show you the total for each.

Comment: That works for 1 specific sales person, but my issue is I have about 5 sales people who cover different areas.

Sales person 1 works in TX CA and FL like the query you wrote, however Sales Person 2 works in GA and NY. Sales Person 3 works in NH and WA. I know I could just write one query for each but I am trying to have one combined query that allows me to output a total for each. I'm not familiar with Indexes but maybe I could use that?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated the query. You can do it in a single query as shown above. Does this query give you what you need?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It makes total sense to use the CASE and WHEN. Thank you very much!